# "mkdir: /us: Read-only file system" error while creating path for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

(I have an Apple M1 MacBook Air)
I am trying to create the path after installation of Tomcat. But I am unable to do it using the terminal because root access is denied after macOS.

I saw one solution on the web, which was: restart your computer in recovery mode, and then put the following command in your terminal:
`csrutil disable`
but I haven't tried it because I can't understand if there will be any side effects or not.
I'm sorry for the basic nature of this question, I'm new to this, and a little worried to experiment. Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I know very little about the latest Apple stuff but not having root access to *your own machine* sounds really bad...Having said that, if the file system is somehow mounted read-only, you really need to look into why it is

Comment: You might try asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, if you're creating a directory off root, you prob. shouldn't be, but again, you ought to be able to